# edit text keyboard disapears on double press grrrrr

Tags: java, android

I'm making a login screen and having trouble with the edit text keyboard disappearing. The app loads, then you would enter your name in the first edit text, But sometimes it dosen't load the keyboard up. So you press it again and it dosen't show. The only way to get it to show again is by clicking the second edit text called `etPassword`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
    tvAboutus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAboutus);
    tvContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
    tvDonate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDonate);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    cbRememberme = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberme);

    etUsername.setOnClickListener(this);
    etPassword.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAboutus.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvContact.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvDonate.setOnClickListener(this);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    etUsername.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                // hide virtual keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm =
                    (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    etPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                // hide virtual keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm2 =
                    (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm2.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Try to remove those calls and add this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

in your `onCreate()`. This will force keyboard to appear automatically.